# How to filter div elements by ID for gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a music library for my website and I want to know if its possible to make clickable filters with jquery. like if I give "X" amount of Divs an Id of music and "x" amount of divs and ID of "video" but they are in no specific order how do I filter out one or the other with an onClick function.... SO if I make a menu that says Music and Videos and both are clickable links, is it possible to click the "music" button or link and hide all elements with the id of VIdeo?

I hope I asked that right. I am trying to make a discography gallery that I want to be responsive so my html will look something like this

FYI I am using bootstrap grid system

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!--This is the filter menu-->
   <div class="well">
      Filters Catagory<br><b><a href="#">All</a> <a href="#">Music <a href="#">Videos</a> <a href="#">Singles</a> </b>
  </div>

<!--end of the filter menu-->

<!--Filterable content-->
 <div id="music">ImG SRC HERE</div>
<div id="music">ImG SRC HERE</div>
<div id="music">ImG SRC HERE</div>
<div id="music">ImG SRC HERE</div>
<div id="videos">ImG SRC HERE</div>
<div id="video">ImG SRC HERE</div>


<div id="video">ImG SRC HERE</div>
<div id="music">ImG SRC HERE</div>
<div id="video">ImG SRC HERE</div>
<div id="music">ImG SRC HERE</div>


<div id="music">ImG SRC HERE</div>
<div id="music">ImG SRC HERE</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Side note **ID** must be unique on a page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give both types a common class and a class for the type:

```
<div class="media music">ImG SRC HERE</div>
<div class="media videos">ImG SRC HERE</div>
```

Then on your links use an attribute to declare type

```
<a href="#" class="filter_link" data-filter="all">All</a> 
<a href="#" class="filter_link" data-filter="music">Music</a> 
<a href="#" class="filter_link" data-filter="videos">Videos</a>
```

Now use the attributes and classes together in click handler

```
// cache collection of elements so only one dom search needed
var $mediaElements = $('.media');

$('.filter_link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the category from the attribute
    var filterVal = $(this).data('filter');

    if(filterVal === 'all'){
      $mediaElements.show();
    }else{
       // hide all then filter the ones to show
       $mediaElements.hide().filter('.' + filterVal).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Much more efficient than my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

First off, id's are unique so you're going to want to switch to classes. After that, do something like:

```
function filter(class) {
    $('div').not('.' + class).hide();
}
```

And call this function when your filter is clicked. This will allow you to use the same function for all of them, and simply pass the class you would like to filter for specifically

Answer (score 1):

You had a typo in your links. You forgot to close your Music link tag.

An `id` is supposed to be unique, so you can't have multiple elements with an `id` of music or video, but that's easily fixed if you use classes instead.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#all').click(function(){
    $('.item').show();
    return false;
  });
  
  $('#music').click(function(){
    $('.item').show();
    $('.item').not('.music').hide();
    return false;
  });
  
  $('#videos').click(function(){
    $('.item').show();
    $('.item').not('.video').hide();
    return false;
  });
  
  $('#singles').click(function(){
    $('.item').show();
    $('.item').not('.single').hide();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
div.music::after {
  content: ' --music';
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div.video::after {
  content: ' --video';
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!--This is the filter menu-->
  <div class="well">
    Filters Catagory
    <br>
    <b>
      <a id="all" href="#">All</a>
      <a id="music" href="#">Music</a>
      <a id="videos" href="#">Videos</a>
      <a id="singles" href="#">Singles</a>
    </b>
  </div>

  <!--end of the filter menu-->

  <!--Filterable content-->
  <div class="music item">ImG SRC HERE</div>
  <div class="music item">ImG SRC HERE</div>
  <div class="music item">ImG SRC HERE</div>
  <div class="music item">ImG SRC HERE</div>
  <div class="video item">ImG SRC HERE</div>
  <div class="video item">ImG SRC HERE</div>


  <div class="video item">ImG SRC HERE</div>
  <div class="music item">ImG SRC HERE</div>
  <div class="video item">ImG SRC HERE</div>
  <div class="music item">ImG SRC HERE</div>


  <div class="music item">ImG SRC HERE</div>
  <div class="music item">ImG SRC HERE</div>

</div>
```

I also created a [demo](http://codepen.io/Ghodmode/pen/zrdvjg) at CodePen.

There's probably a more efficient solution, but this works. You'd probably also be better off using `<button>` elements instead of links.

The CSS I added was just to make it easier for me to see / confirm what was happening.

Comment: Thank you very much this actually worked perfectly.... One last question is there anyway to animate them to fade in?

Comment: Sure. Take a look at [.fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/). Actually, use the solution by @charlietfl and use `.fadeIn('slow')` instead of `.show()`. My solution works, but his is better and easier to maintain.

Comment: I created a [demo](http://codepen.io/Ghodmode/pen/ZQJBra) at CodePen based on the solution by @charlietfl using `.fadeIn('slow')`.